# I programmatically determine operating system in Java?

Tags: java, properties, system

I learn the system features as follows:

```
System.getProperty("os.arch")
```

Output for 64 bit computer: amd64

but when I use a 32 bit java version on a 64 bit computer, the result is: x86

How can I learn the correct result even though I have java 32 bit java installed on a 64 bit computer?

Thank you

Comment: Well, x86 is 32 bit.

Comment: `System.getProperty("os.name")` should return stuff like `Windows 10`. You are talking about `os.arch`. And well, `x86` *is* 32 bit.

Answer (score 2):

This topic is [covered by the Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) from Oracle.

- "os.arch" Operating system architecture
- "os.name" Operating system name
- "os.version"  Operating system version

The values for `os.arch` are explained on Wikipedia.

- `x86` signifies the 32-bit architecture originally from [Intel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel).
- `amd64` signifies the 64-bit extension of that architecture, invented by [AMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Micro_Devices), later adopted by Intel as well.

(By the way, other architectures exist, such as [ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture).)

The first means Java is running on a 32-bit machine, *or* Java is running on a 64-bit machine in 32-bit compatibility mode.

The second means Java is running in 64-bit mode on a 64-bit machine.

> How can I learn the correct result even though I have java 32 bit java installed on a 64 bit computer?

(A) I don’t know. (B) Your Question is moot. The 32-bit version of the JVM running on a 64-bit machine has the constraints of a 32-bit machine. The JVM only sees what appears to be a 32-bit machine. From the perspective of Java, the fact that the host hardware and OS may be 64-bit is irrelevant.